# Ask rating through email

Tags: php, html, css, email, html-email

In my application we will get the feedback from the user by sending the emails to them. So that if the user fills the fields and submits then i'm storing it in my database.

I have prepared an html mail which look like this.

[image: This what i am getting in email]

But the problem here is i am unable to show the rating stars in the mail. which requires inline css but i am unable to put that css in inline as that includes onhover css.

So is there any way to send the ratings through email.

Is there any way to the css on onhover inline
Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe base64 encode the rating star images (i assume they're images)

Comment: @gwillie sorry i didn't get you is there any way to do the same thing with proper start images

Comment: @PavanKumar What he was proposing is to encode the images in `base64` which would reduce the size yet allow them to be used. The original images would still be used, they're just smaller in code.

Comment: @Derija93 i can display the image but on hover of that i have to apply the another sytle. But email don't allow us to write the css other than inline css.

Comment: Have you tried `onhover="..."` instead of CSS?

Comment: Don't forget that Outlook 2007+ uses Word's HTML rendering system which is terrible (worse than IE6's, in fact!). Given the popularity of Outlook I would instead link to a survey online rather than embedding it in the email. Just my opinion.

Comment: @Dai thank you for your valuable suggestion

Comment: @rybo111 but email wont let us to run even javascript also

Comment: Looking for the more answers with in two days otherwise John's answer will get the bounty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try over ruling your inline css with `!important` in your onhover css.

Thinking about the bigger picture however - forms are not fully supported in html email, so depending on your list, you could have 20%+ not able to use them. (form support chart [here](http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/) or [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/))

With this in mind, for 100% support, most email marketers send them to a landing page that hosts the form instead. Another option is to capture basic information using simple href tags and URL parameters. Something like this:

```
<!-- use star images that pass a custom url with user info -->
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com?name=your.subscriber@gmail.com&rating=1"><img alt="1" src="" width="40" height="40" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;"></a>
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com?name=your.subscriber@gmail.com&rating=2"><img alt="2" src="" width="40" height="40" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;"></a>
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com?name=your.subscriber@gmail.com&rating=3"><img alt="3" src="" width="40" height="40" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;"></a>
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com?name=your.subscriber@gmail.com&rating=4"><img alt="4" src="" width="40" height="40" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;"></a>
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com?name=your.subscriber@gmail.com&rating=5"><img alt="5" src="" width="40" height="40" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe inline CSS is impossible, so you need to find a workaround. Maybe creating a flash applet with an animated star or even all 5 stars that would generate a GET/POST request when clicked? The applet could store a unique ID that would link the GET/POST request with this very form submission that would be sent by the user using Submit button.
You need to check that popular webmails don't block flash applets.

Comment: What about if the user don't have the flash player installed for his system or browser

Comment: Then he will probably get nothing. I know it's not the best solution.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just nice looking form? Maybe just add some normal CSS to your radio to make it look nicer? Even Google when sending forms to people in email uses only standard HTML controls without any graphics.

Comment: Yeah but i have already done this as sending link to the user. So, if using that link user can give feedback from my webpage.

Comment: I am searching for alternate solution so that i can have good look and feel even in the mail itself. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` attributes to HTML element, but it's possible that Gmail and other email providers will strip it out.

Comment: Can we execute java script on email

Comment: I think it depends on the specific webmail provider - probably some will allow it and some will not. Alas, I suspect that the majority of them do not allow Javascript.