# Interactive Email

Tags: html, email

wondering if anyone know if this is possible.

A client wants to send an email out that has interactivity within it so the user clicks some radio buttons in the email and then clicks submit to submit the answers.

I have only created the standard html table emails with links and images and nothing as 'complex' as this.

Is this even possible?

My only solution i could think of is send them to a direct link that the form is open in a webpage and the results are submitted in a database of some sort.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I think this is really an "no one ever tried that". Most mail clients will display HTML mails in a real (embedded) browser, so you should be able to use almost anything that HTML has to offer. A form should definitely work.

Comment: I know some form elements will work in different clients, it was really the users answers and the submit then what to do after that. Something i've never come across in an actual email rather than on a webpage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forms are not well supported in html email. You are better off sending them to a landing page for any advanced data capture. For any 1-click-submit radio button like functionality, you could use custom URLs to pass the info on. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900691/ask-rating-through-email/19908435#19908435)