# How to get a checkbox checked in a replied email

Tags: forms, checkbox, html-email

I create a mail in Libreoffice which contains two option values (Yes-No).

Then I copy and paste all into a body message and send it to someone. He receives the mail okay and he is able to make a selection but it cannot be done after selecting Reply and of course I don't get the option answer back.

Is it possible to let the receiver to check an option in a replying answer?

Answer (score 1):

Forms are not supported across major email clients in html-email. Your best bet is to have two links, one that triggers yes, and one that triggers no.

Here is a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900691/ask-rating-through-email/19908435#19908435).