# Technique to send and collect response(s) from survey via email

Tags: javascript, email, html-email

Working on a solution for a customer service oriented business that currently collects customer feedback via printed survey's that customers fill out after their purchase. I've been tasked with creating a way to collect the surveys via the web so information is real-time and  doesn't have to be entered by employees after-the-fact.

Customers email's are already stored in the database. I'm trying to come up with a means of collecting the survey's that yields the largest amount of survey's answered.

The survey is very simple, 2-5 questions rating Bad,Ok,Great or Excellent. I've done some research on html emails, and there seems to be a great deal of limitations which seems unfortunate, because it would be very simple for the end user to just open the email and click the respective button for each question and have that action post to the server.

In my research, it seems javascript is pretty much outlawed from html emails. **Is there a technique by which dynamic content can be present in an email?** For example, have a default content, make a get request to server to check if survey id has been answered or not, if it has been answered load thank you content, if it has not been answered load questions. If loaded question, on click answer to question post request to server...

Thinking as an end user, this would seem like a much better experience then "click here to answer survey" and be redirected to a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of doing dynamic content post-send. The only thing you can change up in an email after sending is an image, as it is hosted on a server.

Without sending them to a landing page, [this is your only 100% supported option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900691/ask-rating-through-email/19908435#19908435). However this will only work for a single multi-choice question without them switching back and forth.