# Can an android app listen to Yes/No from an email or a text?

Tags: android, email, sms, jakarta-mail

I have designed an application that will `send an email` to all addresses in an `sqlite database` to check their availability.

Is there any way that the people receiving these emails can reply with a yes/no and the app would listen and take in what the reply was?

If this is not possible for email, can it be done with a yes/no text message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306150/read-and-display-incoming-message-text-android

Comment: In my experience, the more specific you question is, the better. For example, in this case you might have asked only about SMS, or only about email. Don't worry too much though; having only one downvote is not that bad!

Comment: Haha okay i get you! I made a specific question to the email previously and no response, so thought that if i made it less specific i would get more help, and voila... :)

Answer (score 1):

The replies could certainly be sent as a response to your message and end up in the mailbox corresponding to the sender of your message.  Your app could monitor that mailbox for new messages and process them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JS in an email, and forms have spotty support ([more info](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/)). You can instead use href links with unique urls to respond to a single question.

[See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900691/ask-rating-through-email/19908435#19908435).